# Button to save image to phone on a website

Tags: android, ios, iphone, image, camera-roll

Is it possible to create a button, on a website, that would save an image to someone's camera roll on either iOS or Android? I've searched left and right for this but to no avail. I don't even know if it's possible or not.

Thanks!

Comment: You want the website to automatically cause a phone or tablet to download and install a file?   You might have better luck writing the app side for either iOS or Android to install the image rather than website code attempting to circumvent all security functions on the phone.

Comment: Automatically? No. I wouldn't want to trick anyone into downloading unwanted files. I was wondering if it was possible to call the save image function, but from another button. Maybe it comes with a confirmation window, I don't know. I've been searching for a good hour trying to find information, couldn't find any.

Comment: In fact, I'd much rather let the user use the default phone function, but I'm using a script that makes a pinch zoom on the image. When I press the image to bring the menu up, it simply selects the image and I can't use the save function. The button would be a way to circumvent this conflict.